# In r, how would I remove strata from 3-dimensional contingency tables depending on the number of observations in the strata?

Tags: r

I'm building 3d contingency tables from 3 variables in a data frame.  Let's suppose I'm constructing these via

```
table(x,y,z)
```

Where z is the variable on which I'm stratifying.  I'd like to get rid of any `(,,z(i))` where the number of observations in that stratum is 1.

How might I do this? I had trouble figuring out how to count observations in the first place, which I thought I'd be able to use, with subset, to pare down my contingency tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your data is contained in a data frame object named `data`, this code should remove all data in strata with one observation.

```
data <- data[-which(data$z %in% which(table(data$z)==1)),]
```

**EDIT**

This appears to work now. I'm not sure if this will work in general, but it works for this situation.

```
data <- read.csv(file='~/Downloads/juveniles2forMax.csv')

data <- data.frame(
  Urban = data$Urban,
  RecidivismPlacement = data$RecidivismPlacement,
  timeinjj = data$timeinjj
)

removeStrata <- function(data, z) {
    data[-which(data[,z] %in% as.numeric(attr(which(table(data[,z])==1),"names"))),]
}

removeStrata(data=data, z='timeinjj')
```

Comment: Looks Brilliant, Max, and I think I understand the logic. Only, I get the "$ Operator is Invalid for atomic vectors." Do you have a sense of why this might be happening?

Comment: Perhaps I'd misunderstood your approach: I'd thought 'data' in your example referred to the contingency tables, not the original data. Nevertheless, if I try it on the data frame, the result is a list of integers whose length is approx rxc of the data frame.

Comment: I should have explained it a bit more. It's on the original data. It removes rows with a stratum matching a stratum with one observation. The new data frame should have the same number of columns as the original.

Comment: For whatever reason, the new one doesn't; it went from a frame with three columns (x,y,z) to one that is a list of integers (n = 3*r*c of orig. data frame - 1).  I could understand, perhaps, if it was 3*r*c - the number of obs from strata that contained only one obs, but there were 3 (and not one) of those.  Again, really appreciate your suggestions on this question.

Comment: This is the example I've been using and it works just fine. `data <- expand.grid(x=1:3,y=1:3,z=1:3,KEEP.OUT.ATTRS=FALSE);
data <- rbind(data, c(1,2,4), c(1,2,5));
data <- data[-which(data$z %in% which(table(data$z)==1)),]`

Comment: Hmm ... could the difference be because my 'x' and 'y' only take the values 0 and 1? I've seen this

    $ Operator is Invalid for atomic vectors 

Business before but never really understood what it meant.  Just tried your steps out and they absolutely work, and are essentially what I'm looking for, too.

Comment: @dubhousing The `$` operator is invalid for atomic vectors because it pulls out columns by name, of which an atomic vector has none.

Comment: do you have any thoughts as to why that msg might be coming up for me?

Comment: @dubhousing If you post some sample code that doesn't run there's a much better chance that I'll be able to fix the problem.

Comment: Here's what I'm facing:
I have a frame with 433 obs and 23 vars.  The r and c variables are 'Urban' and 'RecidivismPlacement', and the stratification variable is 'timeinjj'. 'Urban' and 'RecidivismPlacement' take the values 0 or 1; 'timeinjj' takes one of 12 values. I make a new frame with
`Urban <- cbind(Urban,RecidivismPlacement,timeinjj)`
And then attempt to apply the code you suggested:
`stratUrban <- Urban[-which(Urban$timeinjj %in% which(table(Urban$timeinjj)==1)),]`
And the system responds:
`Error in Urban$timeinjj : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: I also happened to just try: `stratUrban <- Urban[-which(Urban[,3] %in% which(table(Urban[,3])==1)),]` and the resulting stratUrban frame has all rows from Urban, except those in which the ~value~ of the third variable was 1 (not where the count of values = 1). Confused! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @dubhousing Try converting `Urban` to a data frame.

Comment: OK, so I did `Urban <- as.data.frame(Urban)`, and then `stratUrban <- Urban[-which(Urban$timeinjj %in% which(table(Urban$timeinjj)==1)),]` ... no $ errors this time but the result is the same as when I used [,3] -- it removed all rows where the _value_ of the third variable, and not the _count_ of the values, was 1.

Comment: @dubhousing That's odd because I'm still getting the correct answer and it looks like your code is the same as mine. Try going step-by-step. First, look at `table(Urban$timeinjj)==1`. What does that give? Then look at `which(table(Urban$timeinjj)==1)`. What does that give? Finally, look at `which(Urban$timeinjj %in% which(table(Urban$timeinjj)==1))`.

Comment: I made a function that works for me. Try putting your data through it using `data` as your data frame and `z` as the name of the stratification variable. `f <- function(data, z) {data[-which(data$z %in% which(table(data$z)==1)),]}` A call to this function would look like `f(data=data, z=z)` without quotes on either parameter.

Comment: Maddening! `table(Urban$timeinjj)==1` gives exactly what I'd expect (I think): a list of strata with logicals indicating whether they have only one observation. `which(table(Urban$timeinjj)==1)` gives `-983 -2 8` with some integers beneath them `1 3 12`, which I don't know how to interpret.  Then, though,  `which(Urban$timeinjj %in% which(table(Urban$timeinjj)==1))` is a list of the row numbers where timeinjj = 1. Similarly, the function `f`, when applied to my data and timeinjj, just removes all the rows from Urban where z had the value of 1.

Comment: Is there any way for you to post your data in a csv file or something?

Comment: yes! I'm amazed by and really appreciate your willingness to help.  Sharing via google drive: [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B57G363kqAZ3MWg3SE5fb01wMmc)
Nothing that needs to be anonymized or hush-hushed there.
And just to remind, I'm trying to demo this with the variables `Urban`, `RecidivismPlacement`, and `timeinjj`

Comment: @dubhousing See my edit above. I have no idea why this was working on my original data set but not on yours. In any case, that's bad. Hopefully the new version works.

Comment: Thanks so much Max! Will test after dinner and give you all due thanks, applause, offerings, hugs, etc.  Have a great week!